# How do I look for a file and execute it via DOS?

Tags: loops, for-loop, arguments, dos, dir

The title is pretty much self explanatory and my example makes it pretty obvious but I'm trying to find for a particular exe file and execute it.

```
cd c:\

for /f %%f in ('dir /b /s eclipse.exe') do (
    start %%f -clean
)

echo Done!  
pause >nul
```

For safety reason please let me know if it's possible to run only the first file found or look for a particular hash string or file size.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To run only the first file found (`"tokens=*"` to eliminate spaces in path(s); note also [required empty string](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) `""` in `start "" "%%f" -clean`)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /s eclipse.exe') do (
    start "" "%%f" -clean
    goto :enough
)
:enough
echo Done
```

To look for file size

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /s eclipse.exe') do (
   for /F "tokens=3" %%H in ('dir "%%f"^|find /I "%%~nxf"') do (
      @echo %%f size=%%H
   )
)
```

To look for a particular hash string: in `cmd` line need an external tool like [File Checksum Integrity Verifier (FCIV)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) or better [HashMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html) etc.

In Windows PowerShell: `Get-FileHash` computes the hash value for a file by using a specified hash algorithm.